# Subtract the value of two columns by 1 from a variable

Tags: r

How to subtract from a data.frame the value of two columns by 1

So far I couldn't find anything about how to address a column from a data.frame and subtract all values at one

myData:

```
src target
 1      1  
 2      2
 3      3   
 4      4
```

Should become:

```
src target
 0      0  
 1      1
 2      2   
 3      3
```

Comment: Just do `df2 <- df1 - 1`

Comment: Great thanks! there is a way to address only the first two columns?

Comment: `df[, 1:2] <- df[, 1:2] -1`

Answer (score 0):

If we need to subtract the last two columns, get the last columns extracted with `tail`

```
nm1 <- tail(names(df1), 2)
df2 <- df1[nm1] -1
```

Comment: actually i wanted the first two columes but thanks now i understood :)  nm1 <- head(names(df1), 2)

Comment: @Peter If you don't need to update the original dataset, create a new identifier